# Why doesn't my character attack while moving diagonally?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

[image]I've followed some simple tutorials on Udemy and Youtube, and I created a player controller that involves walking and attacking. I cannot seem to figure out why I can't attack while holding down 2 directional inputs. The attack animation plays when I am moving up and right, but not down/right, down/left, or up/left.

Here is the code I am using

```
    void Update()
{
    //Movement

    theRB.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"))) * moveSpeed;

    myAnim.SetFloat("moveX", theRB.velocity.x);
    myAnim.SetFloat("moveY", theRB.velocity.y);

    //Attack

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Attack();
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        myAnim.SetTrigger("Attack");
    }


}
```

I understand that the Attack() method has no effect yet besides the animation, but I cannot get the animation to play while moving diagonally. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth putting the AttackCode before the movement Code.

Comment: okeydokey! can you please edit your post to include a screenshot of the animator?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me explain you bitwise
that you can't run 2 animations at a time when using Unity animator. I think that you might be using kinda this

[image: No use of any state]

Instead of beating from any state. I mean see it will be on IDLE by default and it will only attack if the character is on IDLE animation. So to prevent this you can use

[image: With use of any state]

What it will do is it will set the player even if it's walking. You must set back transition to IDLE if not walking and back transition to walking if it's walking. If you are doing this mistake I hope so you got your answer.

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't seem to fix the problem.  I'm not sure if it is an animator issue. Thank you for the comment. :)

Comment: Can you please explain your problem more like by giving a video/ some image as Peter Hayman asked in comments?

Comment: When I press w and a, to move up and to the left are the same time, the space bar does not trigger an attack. I've found that my problem goes away when I switch the attack button from space, to the mouse button. I'll try to get pictures and videos when I'm able. Sorry lol, I've been very busy with work. Thank you